# Replace string with respective matching one

Tags: r

I need to replace the strings in df2 with the partially matching string in df1 .

Like 1MG Solution has 1MG in df1 as well thus need to replace it with 1MG from df1 .
This needs to be done for million records .

```
  > df1
          A       
        1MG             
        ABOF          
        Amazon        
        American Swan
        Clovia       

    > df2


      A                 B                                          
1MG Solution           1MG
ABOF Prime             ABOF
Dual Command           NA
Amazon AWF             AMazon
American Swan Fi       AMerican Swan
Clovia World Spaces    Clovia
Shape Makers           NA
Unions                 NA
```

Comment: You can use `grep`

Comment: Can you show me ? I'm just a beginner :)

Comment: I guess the expected output is the 'B' column in 'df2'?

Comment: Yes , its B Column in df2 .

Comment: Need to look [Regular Expression](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) and way to use it in R. Take a look to the StringR package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`stringr` package is ideal for such operations,

```
library(stringr)
df2$B <- str_extract(df2$A, paste(df1$A, collapse = '|'))
df2
#                    A             B
#1        1MG Solution           1MG
#2          ABOF Prime          ABOF
#3        Dual Command          <NA>
#4          Amazon AWF        Amazon
#5    American Swan Fi American Swan
#6 Clovia World Spaces        Clovia
#7        Shape Makers          <NA>
#8              Unions          <NA>
```

Note: You will need to convert your variables to character( If they are factors)

Answer (score 0):

By using `grep` function you can find if any of the pattern in the first dataframe is present in a second.
For example :

```
df <- data.frame(A=c("1MG","ABOF","Amazon","American Swan","Clovia"))
label=c("1MG Sol","ABOF Prim",
"Dual Command","Amazon AWF","something else",
"American Swan Fi","Clovia World Spaces")
apply(df,1,function(x) grep(x,label)) #will return the matching postion
```

The apply function will return the matching position :

```
> apply(df,1,function(x) grep(x,label))
[1] 1 2 4 6 7
```

I think you could find a solution in this way